# Последствия моего варианта PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

В общем и целом для работы с `JDBC-mysql` у меня есть только три типа данных:
`Integer, String, Long`

Я не любитель усложнять, но все-таки для удобства создал такой `PreparedStatement:`

```
private final int STR = 1, INT = 2, LONG = 3;

private class Param {
    private int type, valueInt;
    private long valueLong;
    private String valueString;
    private Param(int type, String valueString) {
        this.type = type;
        this.valueString = valueString;
    }
    private Param(int type, int valueInt) {
        this.type = type;
        this.valueInt = valueInt;
    }
    private Param(int type, long valueLong) {
        this.type = type;
        this.valueLong = valueLong;
    }
}
private PreparedStatement prepareStatement(Connection connection, String sql, Param... params) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement prst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        switch (params[i].type) {
            case STR: prst.setString(i + 1, params[i].valueString); break;
            case INT: prst.setInt(i + 1, params[i].valueInt); break;
            case LONG: prst.setLong(i + 1, params[i].valueLong); break;
        }
    }
    return prst;
}
```

Собственно делалось это для читаемого `try-with-resourse`:

```
try (PreparedStatement prst = prepareStatement(connection, "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE id = ? AND age = ? AND time = ? LIMIT 1",
         new Param(STR, "value"),
         new Param(INT, 123),
         new Param(LONG, 123L));
     ResultSet rs = prst.executeQuery()) {
    //...
}
```

Тоесть здесь у меня все удобно все красиво...

А есть еще вот такой известный всем вариант:

```
private PreparedStatement prepareStatement(Connection connection, String sql, Object... params) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement prst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        prst.setObject(i + 1, params[i]);
    }
    return prst;
}
```

И собственно он еще удобнее и красивее:

```
try (PreparedStatement prst = prepareStatement(connection, "SELECT * FROM " + table + " WHERE id = ? AND age = ? AND time = ? LIMIT 1", "value", 123, 123L);
     ResultSet rs = prst.executeQuery()) {
    //...
}
```

Но тут нет того, что мне важно - **четкости**.
Да и определение типа данных это тоже накладные расходы.
Особенно если клиентов онлайн 1000+ и от каждого ежесекундно поступают запросы.

**Вопрос:** чем я рискую и рискую ли вообще в своей реализации используя класс `Param` ?
Если есть вариант лучше, пожалуйста дайте пример.

**UPD:**
Еще вот такой вариант `Param`:

```
private final int STR = 1, INT = 2, LONG = 3;

private class Param {
    private int type, valueInt;
    private long valueLong;
    private String valueString;
    private Param setString(String valueString) {
        this.type = STR;
        this.valueString = valueString;
        return this;
    }
    private Param setInt(int valueInt) {
        this.type = INT;
        this.valueInt = valueInt;
        return this;
    }
    private Param setLong(long valueLong) {
        this.type = LONG;
        this.valueLong = valueLong;
        return this;
    }
}

new Param(STR, value) vs new Param().setString(value)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно определение *четкости*. Определение типа можно перенести внутрь конструктора `Param`, ведь тип уже известен, и снять с пользователя обязанность указывать тип. Определение типа не затратная операция, можно не переживать.

Comment: А зачем если те же действия может выполнить сам PreparedStatement используя setObject(1, object), но это будет дольше, чем явное указание типа, потому и спрашиваю про риски Param

Comment: Я нагуглил много тестов где сравнивали `instanceof vs switch vs if else` и там все-таки есть разница

Comment: Так вы явно тип нигде не указываете. Когда создаете экземпляр класса `Param(int, String)` `Param(int, int)` `Param(int, long)`, всегда идет выбор конструктора в зависимости от второго аргумента, и не зависит от первого. В любом случае, использую `PreparedStatement` вам надо знать тип аргумента.

Comment: Ну конструктор переберет 3 варианта, а не тучу как Prepared. Конструктор же можно вообще не использовать, а создать методы тотже new Param().setString(value). Я добавлю в вопрос еще вариант с методами

Comment: Можно сделать статические методы генерации. Просто, не понятна цель оптимизации? В указанном примере самая затратная операция, это работа с БД, и время выполнения этих запросов в разы больше, чем `instanceof vs switch vs if else`. Если требования к коду - минимальное время ответа (например, для трейдинга), то нужно кэшировать объекты, данные, выносить логику принятия решения и т.д. Если это обычная работа 1000+ запросов, то гонка за микросекундами не целесообразна, когда вы обращаетесь к БД через драйвер.

Comment: Да именно - минимальное время ответа. Это онлайн игра, данные циркулируют без остановки и небольшими кусками.

Comment: Тут скорее не цель оптимизации, а вопрос "есть ли разница?" и по сути она есть, но я хочу выявить подводные камни. Опять же повторюсь `instanceof` это вообще один из самых медленных операторов, а если я его задействую в таком масштабе, то производительность точно упадет и возможно увеличится пинг из-за вот этого микро-простоя при переборе типов. Хотя может я и не прав.

Comment: А что значит "для читаемого try-with-resourse"?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev ну это я так выразился в плане красивого и удобного try-with-resourse. Тоесть - 'все на своем месте'

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что такой вариант более прост и понятен:

```
public static void setParam(PreparedStatement prstmt, int parameterIndex, String value) throws SQLException {
    prstmt.setString(parameterIndex, value);
}

public static void setParam(PreparedStatement prstmt, int parameterIndex, int value) throws SQLException {
    prstmt.setInt(parameterIndex, value);
}

public static void setParam(PreparedStatement prstmt, int parameterIndex, long value) throws SQLException {
    prstmt.setLong(parameterIndex, value);
}

...

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
setParam(preparedStatement, 1, "StringValue");
setParam(preparedStatement, 2, 10);
setParam(preparedStatement, 2, 15L);
```